# A majority of my iframes load succesfully, but then a handful are blocked by firefox. 'Load denied by X-Frame-Options: “DENY”'

Tags: firefox, iframe, http-headers, x-frame-options

[screenshot of the firefox console that shows my issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K3iBb.jpg)
There are about 100 iframes on this page, and handful get blocked by the x frame options, while the others are not. The iframes are all from the same website. Why do only a few get blocked?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/W1zlx.jpg

Answer (score 0):

> Why do only a few get blocked?

Because only a few websites actively deny other websites permission to display them in frames.

Comment: So the site only denies permission for specific pages to be displayed in frames.

Comment: they are all the same page, and the site doesn't restrict iframe usage, it offers it without restriction, also they work fine in chrome, this question pertains to firefox

Comment: @TrevorO'Farrell — The URLs are different, so it isn't the same page (although it is a similar one). It is either a bug in the site, a bug in Firefox or you are wrong about it restricting iframe usage.

Comment: I'd speculate a bug, as they offer for you to embed games in every game analysis, any way of disabling X frame options? This is a flask web app i'm building, getting these errors running it on localhost.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my own issue by lazy loading each iframe, using this git repo: https://github.com/verlok/lazyload
I suspect either lichess(the site I was loading iframes from) or Firefox, aren't able to deal with how many iframes i was loading at a given time, causing a few to be blocked.